# AJAX POST Request in Laravel says url not found

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, routes

I am trying to post data to a controller through ajax request. But it can't find the route and says the following in console.

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/addNotification_action 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my ajax call below.

```
    function editNotification(obj) {
    // alert(obj.id);
    var obj_id = obj.id;
    var id = obj_id.split("_");
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('addNotification_action') }}",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {edit_notification_id: id[1]},
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#title').val(result['title']);
        $('#description_notification').val(result['details']);
        $('#edit_flag_notification').val(result['notification_id']);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });

}
```

And I am just trying to dd() the request I get in the controller. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a route set up for that `/addNotification_action` url? Please post it

Comment: Show your route code

Comment: Route::post('admin/addNotification_action', ['uses' => 'AdminController@addNotification']);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create a route and give this route a name. You have to generate the ajax url as "route('route_name')".

```
// Route (for Laravel 8)
Route::post('addNotification_action', [NotificationController::class, 'notify_method'])->name('notify');

// Ajax Settings
....
url: "{{ route('notify') }}",
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Jus Give `admin/addNotification_action` in Ajax URL

Comment: ok now the route is working but instead of dd(''this") it is saying 419 page expired. The controller only has this code. dd('$request')

Comment: Sorry For Late Replay, You Need To Pass Access Token @HamzaKhan

Comment: added the token to header now it says this->  Uncaught ReferenceError: editSignal is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (notifications:276)

Comment: editSignal is the javascript function that has ajax